# Websocket stream listen listening to multiple times

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket

I've initialized a WebSocket connection and I'm listening to stream which I've defined as `asBroadcastStream` so it does not return `stream has already been listened to` listening for events from same stream.

Stream is listening to same message multiple times.

For example
On 1st message
Stream prints `data` 1 time

On 2nd message
Stream prints `data` 2 times

On 3rd message
Stream prints `data` 3 times

... and so on.

```
class NotificationController {
  static final NotificationController _singleton =
      NotificationController._internal();

  StreamController<String> streamController =
      StreamController.broadcast(sync: true);

  IOWebSocketChannel? channel;
  late var channelStream = channel?.stream.asBroadcastStream();

  factory NotificationController() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  NotificationController._internal() {
    initWebSocketConnection();
  }

  initWebSocketConnection() async {
    var storedUserInfo = storage.getUserInfoStorage();
    Map storedData = await storedUserInfo;
    String userID = storedData['user_id'];

    print("conecting...");

    try {
      channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
        Uri.parse('ws://127.0.0.1:8001/chat/$userID/'),
        pingInterval: const Duration(seconds: 10),
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return await initWebSocketConnection();
    }

    print("socket connection initializied");
    channel?.sink.done.then((dynamic _) => _onDisconnected());
  }

  void sendMessage(messageObject, Function messageListener) {
    try {
      channel?.sink.add(json.encode(messageObject));
      var mystream = channelStream?.listen((data) {
        print(data);
        Map message = json.decode(data);
        messageListener(message);
      });
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _onDisconnected() {
    initWebSocketConnection();
  }
}
```

Comment: 0

What's the question now? Your post in un clear

Comment: @MuTe33 updated question, hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

You may be initializing the listener multiple times.
put your code where your initialized code is called only once may be initState method or globally.